# Integer objects comparison

Tags: java, oop, integer

```
public class NewClass
 {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
      Integer a = 188;
      Integer b = 188;
      System.out.println(a.intValue() == b); //prints true
   }
}
```

The above code sample prints true. Since I've not considered the integer value for 'b', How is the code compared and TRUE was printed?

Comment: `intValue()` returns `int` and from what I remember `int==Integer` or `Integer==int` is unboxed to `int==int`.

Comment: @GhostCat Found better duplicate. Like always it is good to search [among Jon's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A22656+%5Bjava%5D+unboxed) :)

Comment: You still got the deserved upvote. And an extra badge (unless I miscalculated) for linking to a Skeet answer:-)

Comment: @GhostCat Thx. Sometimes I wish there ware small voting arrows for duplicate link. People could use them to vote if duplicate was correct or not. This would let people show some appreciation toward person who proposed this duplicate (not much to not abuse the system, maybe like edits +2/-2). Hopefully people would be more willing to search for duplicates then.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to me.